# Matching patterns of characters

Tags: c

I was wondering if there are any significant improvements that could be made in order to make the program more concise or efficient, particularly in the `findmatch` function. However there is a catch: I cannot use strings or array notation; working only with `char`s and pointer arithmetic.

In short, the program accepts two user inputs: one for the text, and the other for a pattern. Also, the user has a choice of putting "?" chars as "wild" chars that can be treated as any char.The program finds the start char of the pattern in the text input and prints out the remaining chars in the text after the pattern.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int readline(char* text, int n);
char* findmatch(char* pattern, char* text, int pl, int tl);
void printmessage(char* position, char* text, int pl, int tl); 

int main() {
    char text[40], pattern[40], *position;
    int textlength, patternlength;

    printf("Enter text: ");
    textlength = readline(text, 40);
    printf("Enter pattern: ");
    patternlength = readline(pattern, 40);
    position = findmatch(pattern, text, patternlength, textlength);
    printmessage(position, text, patternlength, textlength);
}

int readline(char* text, int n) {
    int i=0;
    for(i;i<n;i++){
        int ic = getchar();
        if(ic == 10)
            break;
        else{
            *(text+i) = ic;
        }               
     };
     return i;
}

char* findmatch(char* pattern, char* text, int pl, int tl) {
    int indexp = 0;
    char* position = NULL;
    int x=0;
    for(x; x<tl; x++){
        int pc = *(pattern+indexp);
        int tc = *(text+x);
        if(pc == 63 || pc == tc){
            indexp++;
            if(indexp == pl){
                position = (text+x)-indexp+1;
                break;
            }
            printf("status: pass\n");       
        }else{
            indexp = 0;
            printf("status: fail\n");   
        }
    }
    return position;    
}

void printmessage(char* position, char* text, int pl, int tl) {
    if(position == NULL){
        printf("no match\n");
    }else{
        int p = (position-text)+1;
        printf("The pattern was found at char %d. The remaining text chars are: ", p);
        int i = p+pl-1;
        for(i; i<tl; i++){
            printf("%c", *(text+i));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
 }
```

Comment: What's the logic behind the ban on strings and array notation? It shouldn't change your program substantially (other than making it harder to read), I'm just curious.

Comment: Well this program is an assignment for a course that deals with memory and since we are learning about stack frames and things of the nature our professor wants us to know the ins and outs of what we can do with memory addresses and pointers, and how array notation could be substituted with pointer arithmetic. That, and we haven't gotten into strings in C yet.

Comment: `readline()` is a well known system function,  here is how that function is part of the code: `#include <stdio.h>
       #include <readline/readline.h>
       #include <readline/history.h>

       char *
       readline (const char *prompt);`   Suggest using a different name for your function, like: `myReadLine()`

Comment: the posted code contains several 'magic' numbers, (10,40,63).   'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  Suggest using `#define` statements or an`enum` to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then using those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: the `readline()` function can be easily replaced with well known functions like: `fgets( text, sizeof text, stdin);` followed by: `char *newline; if(NULL != (newline =  strchr( text, '\n') ) { *newline = '\0'; }`

Comment: the posted code does not cleanly compile.  1) in `readline()` the statement: `for(i;i<n;i++)` is not correct:  perhaps you meant: `for( i=0; i<n; i++ )` (spaces added for clarity)  2) in `findmatch()` the statement: `for(x; x<tl; x++)` is not correct: perhaps you meant: `for(x=0;  x<tl;  x++ )` (it is also ok to completely eliminate the first parameter (keeping the semicolon) as `x` is already initialized to 0  3) in `printmessage()` the statement: `for(i; i<tl; i++)` is not correct: perhaps you meant: `for( ;  i<tl;  i++ )`

Comment: yes, for each of the `for` statements, it initially gave me trouble when I tried `for(int i=0;...` for example, because I am used to being able to do so in Java, for example. After researching it online, I found that I couldn't instantiate the variable inside the conditional statement, so I just set it outside the for loop. But I'm confused as to what you meant by the code not being able to cleanly compile. When I compile it, it doesn't give me any errors - does that mean that the compiler recognizes the syntax error but can continue without failing? Also, thank you for all the suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following does not address any desired updates to `findmatch()`

But does address the request for improvements to the program.

improvements include:

1. no implicit conversion warnings from the compiler
2. does not use a well known system function name
3. uses system function: `strlen()` to find the length of the string
4. does not produce any compiler warnings
5. uses `fgets()` to read whole line in one operation
6. uses `strchr()` to eliminate any newline read by `fgets()`
7. follows the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement*, resulting in much easier to read/understand code
8. the 'magic' numbers were either eliminated or replaced with meaningful names

and now, the revised code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_INPUT_LEN (40)

// prototypes
size_t myReadLine (char* text, int n);
char* findmatch(char* pattern, char* text, size_t pl, size_t tl);
void printmessage(char* position, char* text, size_t pl, size_t tl);

int main( void )
{
    char text[ MAX_INPUT_LEN ];
    char pattern[ MAX_INPUT_LEN ];
    char *position;
    size_t textlength;
    size_t patternlength;

    printf("Enter text: ");
    textlength = myReadLine( text, (int)(sizeof text) );

    printf("Enter pattern: ");
    patternlength = myReadLine( pattern, sizeof pattern );

    position = findmatch(pattern, text, patternlength, textlength);
    printmessage(position, text, patternlength, textlength);
}



size_t myReadLine( char* text, int n)
{
    size_t i = 0; // initialize to no chars read

    if( NULL != fgets( text, n, stdin ) )
    {
        // eliminate trailing newline, if any
        char * newline;
        if( NULL != ( newline = strchr( text, '\n' ) ) )
        {
            *newline = '\0';
        }

        i = strlen( text );
    }
    return i;
}



char* findmatch(char* pattern, char* text, size_t pl, size_t tl)
{
    size_t indexp = 0;
    char* position = NULL;
    size_t x=0;

    for( ; x<tl; x++)
    {
        int pc = *(pattern+indexp);
        int tc = *(text+x);

        if(pc == '?' || pc == tc)
        {
            indexp++;
            if(indexp == pl)
            {
                position = (text+x)-indexp+1;
                break;
            }
            printf("status: pass\n");
        }

        else
        {
            indexp = 0;
            printf("status: fail\n");
        }
    }
    return position;
}


void printmessage(char* position, char* text, size_t pl, size_t tl)
{
    if(position == NULL)
    {
        printf("no match\n");
    }

    else
    {
        size_t p = (size_t)(position-text)+1;
        printf("%s: %ld. %s\n",
               "The pattern was found at char",
               p,
               "The remaining text chars are: ");
        size_t i =  p+pl-1;

        for(; i<tl; i++)
        {
            printf("%c", *(text+i));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
 }
```